# git(hub) lost all my changes in group project

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I am working on an eclipse project with two friends. We use Git(Hub) to work as efficient as possible. Here is the problem: I worked on the project and uploaded the changes. Unfortunately, my friends were not able to see my modifications. Nevertheless, I was still able to see my new version in eclipse. Now I tried to upload it again but "there was nothing to upload".

Then I used `git fetch` and `rebase` to see if something would happen. 
Unfortunately, all changes are gone now. I used `git commit --amend` and they **"found a swap file by the name xx with the date of my last upload!".**

Does anyone know how can I get back to my working version now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't push your changes after messed up local history, then reset your local with remote.

```
$ git branch <branch-name>                # backup the branch for safety
$ git fetch                               # sync with remote   
$ git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>   # reset local branch with remote branch
```

---

**Alternate:** `git reflog` will show you the whole git history you executed the commands. Copy the last working commit-hash you want to go back.

```
 $ git reflog
```

Checkout to that commit.

```
 $ git checkout <commit-hash>
 $ git log                      # see the commit history
```

If all things are ok. Then checkout to a new branch. If you do any change in new branch then do Add, Commit and Push or, just Push to remote.

```
 $ git checkout -b new-branch   # create a new branch called 'new-branch' and checkout to that branch
 $ git add .
 $ git commit -m 'message'
 $ git push origin HEAD         # push to remote new-branch
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I used git reflog and now I am able to see that commit that I want to get back to (inclusive the code of that commit). Git checkout does not work though. Is there a certain command I can use to get back to that one commit?

Comment: "Git checkout does not work though" what is the error for the command `git checkout <commit-hash>`?

Comment: And I used git commit earlier to upload my changes. Later I used git fetch and rebase to see if somthing happened. Then I used git commit --amend (there my last commit was visible). Then I used git reset -hard and now I used git reflog (where I can see the commit I want to get back to but dont know how)

Comment: Copy the commit-hash of the commit you want to go back then checkout to that commit by `git checkout <commit-hash>`. Does it work?

Comment: It does not work. I copied it and wrote "git checkout <5002cc4>" and it says syntax error?

Comment: you should run `git checkout 5002cc4` :) . `<replace this with your value, also remove left & right bracket>`.

Comment: Now it worked and I see it at git log. What should I do know to get it in eclipse again?

Comment: Follow the answer. You should be able to get it in eclipse automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "$ git checkout -b new-branch"? Did I already do this with the previous step?

Comment: No. Create a new branch and checkout to that branch by `git checkout -b new-branch` command.

Comment: "On branch new-branch nothing to commit, working tree clean" is what I get when I wrote git commit

Comment: Yes, on top is the commit I switched to via git checkout. So now I started eclipse and it worked!! The only problem now is that I dont know how to add it. Should I use git status, git add ., git commit and git push now?

Comment: You can just push to remote `git push origin new-branch`, because you have no uncommitted changes in your local.

Comment: Alright, seems to work. Do you know how to merge it with the master? Because it is a new branch now

Comment: Create a Pull Request using GitHub gui. Or, simply checkout to *master* branch, Merge the *new-branch* with master, Push to *remote master*.
`git checkout master`, `git pull origin new-branch`, `git push origin master`.